# Creating Folder and the user name it using rawinput

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to create a folder inside a certain directory but I want to take an input from user using the ***rawinput*** function.

```
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
parentdir = '/home/waldo/foobar/'
subdir = raw_input('please name subdirectory: ')
dir = os.path.join(parentdir, subdir)
if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.makedirs(dir)
```

Comment: Yes, Like that i want to use this new directory later, so how can i implement '/home/waldo/foobar/dir'

Comment: In the third line of my example, the variable `dir` will be assigned the parent dir plus the name of the subdir typed by the user. I think this is what you want, right?

Comment: Yeah Thanks i got mixed up.